# EBADF in npm create qwik

Tags: file, directory, file-descriptor, error-code, qwik

I'm trying to start a new Qwik app but when I put "npm create qwik@latest" I get this error:

`TTY initialization failed: uv_tty_init returned EBADF (bad file descriptor)`

I searching to solve it but there's no way. I apreciated if someone could give little help.

I tried to uninstall and install again the packages, but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What is your OS? What is your Node version?

Comment: I have this issue to, did you solve this?
I have node version 19.8.1 on Windows

Comment: Try using powershell instead, I just did and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you using git-bash,that's the point,I have this issue too.change to others should be fine.